# sending context of form to other class

Tags: c#

**hi, i have send form context to another class to run function there, but the fun show out the messagebox but not update form text , why ?**

- i need the function start to update form title
- i sending form context to timer class as parameter
- the function start work in interval but the method cant update the
  form control

> this is form class

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            //form constractor 
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        timer mytimer;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Elipse()
        { //the code for timer :) //yazeed coding  
            //MessageBox.Show(" ");
            this.Text=" jkghjg";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mytimer = new timer();
            mytimer.elipse += Elipse;
            mytimer.Interval = 1000;
            mytimer.start(this);
        }
    }
}
```

> this is timer class

```
class timer
{
    bool isstart;
    public delegate void Del();
    public Del elipse;
    public static void UserRep() { }
    public bool Enable { get; set; }
    public int Interval { get; set; }
    public timer()
    {
        Enable = false;
        Interval = 1000;//default is 1 sec
        isstart = false;
        elipse = new Del(UserRep);
    }
    public void start(Form Context)
    {

         Context.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)async delegate
        {
            Enable = true;
            isstart = true;
            do
            {
                await Task.Delay(Interval);
                new Thread(() => 
               {
                   elipse(); //the replacment running now (interface thrad protected)
               }).Start();
            }
            while (isstart);
            Enable = false;
        });
    }
    public void stop()
    {
        isstart = false;
    }
}
```

*AND thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are starting a new thread, you need to call elipse in the Form context:

Replace:

```
               new Thread(() =>
                {
                    elipse(); 
                }).Start();
```

with

```
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Context.BeginInvoke(elipse); 
                }).Start();
```

Comment: Thanks bro, 
invoke not updating UI , we should use "Begin Invoke" instead, 
look next answer

Comment: Updated Answer, tnx

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks *Robert*,  good improvement , the code running successfully i add the post to see what others say, for code correct :)  i keep this method like this for other developer to understand that they can add more code here**

- i find lot of post that they use long code to perform small task,
  here is light code for many methods used in many project and helpful
- this code is same as Microsoft timer implemented by me

> here it is

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            //form constractor 
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        timer mytimer;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //perform event click for button automaticly 
            button1.PerformClick(); 
        }
        private void Elipse()
        {
            //the code for timer :) //yazeed coding  ,,,, write any other code
            new Thread(() => MessageBox.Show("Successful")).Start();
            Text = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Seconds.ToString();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mytimer = new timer();
            mytimer.elipse += Elipse;
            mytimer.Interval = 1000;
            mytimer.Enable = true;
            mytimer.start(this);
        }
    }
}
class timer
{
    bool isstart;
    internal delegate void Del();
    internal Del elipse;
    static void UserRep() { }
    internal bool Enable { get; set; }
    internal int Interval { get; set; }
    internal timer(int val=100)
    {
        Enable = false;
        Interval = val>0?val:100;//default is 1 sec
        isstart = false;
        elipse = new Del(UserRep);
    }
    internal void start(Form Context)
    {
         new Thread(async () =>
        {
            isstart = true;
            do
            {
                await Task.Delay(Interval);
                new Thread(() => Context.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
               {
                   elipse(); //the replacment running now (interface thrad protected)
               })).Start();
            }
            while (isstart);
        }).Start();
    }
    internal void stop()
    {
        isstart = false;
    }
}
```